# XML to CSV using xslt create an extra line

Tags: python, csv, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have this **XML**, and I want to have a csv format:
I'm using python with lxml.etree library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RsuProtocol schemaVersion="1.11" RefSchemaFile="xxxx.xsd">
<UpdateStep>
    <Phase>x1Activation</Phase>
    <TimestampStart>1687771672000</TimestampStart>
    <TimestampEnd>1687771828000</TimestampEnd>
</UpdateStep>
<UpdateStep>
    <Phase>x2Execution</Phase>
    <TimestampStart>1687771828000</TimestampStart>
    <TimestampEnd>1687771907000</TimestampEnd>
    <Warning>
        <WarnCode>0x00000000</WarnCode>
        <Count>2</Count>
        <FirstOccurrence>1687771907</FirstOccurrence>
        <SpecificWarnCode>blablabla</SpecificWarnCode>
        <WarnMessage>Hello</WarnMessage>
    </Warning>
    <Warning>
        <WarnCode>0x11111111</WarnCode>
        <Count>1</Count>
        <FirstOccurrence>1687771907</FirstOccurrence>
        <SpecificWarnCode>helo</SpecificWarnCode>
        <WarnMessage>Hello</WarnMessage>
    </Warning>
</UpdateStep>
<UpdateStep>
    <Phase>x3MguCompletion</Phase>
    <TimestampStart>1687771907000</TimestampStart>
    <TimestampEnd>1687771965000</TimestampEnd>
</UpdateStep>
</RsuProtocol>
```

**I want to have this output:**

```
"1","x1Activation","","2023-06-26 09:27:52.000000000","2023-06-26 09:30:28.000000000","","","","",""
"2","x2Execution","","2023-06-26 09:30:28.000000000","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","0x00000000","2","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","blablabla","Hello"
"3","x2Execution","","2023-06-26 09:30:28.000000000","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","0x11111111","1","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","helo","Hello"
"4","x3Completion","","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","2023-06-26 09:32:45.000000000","","","","",""
```

I'm having this output:

```
"1","x1Activation","","2023-06-26 09:27:52.000000000","2023-06-26 09:30:28.000000000","","","","",""
"2","x2Execution","","2023-06-26 09:30:28.000000000","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","0x00000000","2","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","blablabla","Hello"
"3","x3Completion","","2023-06-26 09:31:47.000000000","2023-06-26 09:32:45.000000000","","","","",""
```

With the xslt that I'm using I'm obtaining only one line for Phase= 'x2Execution', I want to obtain the both "warning" info, one for each line of the phase.

**This is the xslt that I'm using:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/RsuProtocol" name="FBM_UPDATE">
        <xsl:for-each select="UpdateStep">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="Phase"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="DiagnosisAddress"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data">
                    <xsl:call-template name="get-datetime-from-timestamp">
                        <xsl:with-param name="timestamp">
                            <xsl:call-template name="convert-to-null">
                                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="TimestampStart"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'-1'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data">
                    <xsl:call-template name="get-datetime-from-timestamp">
                        <xsl:with-param name="timestamp">
                            <xsl:call-template name="convert-to-null">
                                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="TimestampEnd"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'-1'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="Warning/WarnCode"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="Warning/Count"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data">
                    <xsl:call-template name="get-datetime-from-timestamp">
                        <xsl:with-param name="timestamp">
                            <xsl:call-template name="convert-to-null">
                                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="Warning/FirstOccurrence"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'-1'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="Warning/SpecificWarnCode"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="format-csv-field">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="Warning/WarnMessage"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="no-delim" select="'true'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:value-of select="$new-line"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet you have posted throws errors because the named templates are missing.

Still, I think the actual problem is clear enough, so here is a **simplified** example you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/RsuProtocol">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateStep"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UpdateStep">
    <xsl:variable name="common">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Phase"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="TimestampStart"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="TimestampEnd"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Warning">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Warning">
                <xsl:with-param name="common" select="$common"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:number count="UpdateStep[not(Warning)] | Warning" level="any"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$common"/>
            <xsl:text>"",""&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Warning">
    <xsl:param name="common"/>
    <xsl:number count="UpdateStep[not(Warning)] | Warning" level="any"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$common"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="WarnCode"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Count"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input XML example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
1,x1Activation,1687771672000,1687771828000,"",""
2,x2Execution,1687771828000,1687771907000,0x00000000,2
3,x2Execution,1687771828000,1687771907000,0x11111111,1
4,x3MguCompletion,1687771907000,1687771965000,"",""
```

---

Alternatively, you could do the transformation in 2 passes: first, "flatten" the input by making each warning a full step, containing all the data from the parent step; then process the result uniformly, creating a row for each step.

Comment: Thank you,
What about this first value of each row, the position()? Souldn't we have a for-each for each UpdateStep?

Comment: This is the python script that I'm using
```
file_xslt = "main.xslt"
parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
xslt = ET.parse(file_xslt, parser=parser)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
dom = ET.parse('code/src2.xml')
newdom = transform(dom)
result = str(newdom, 'UTF-8')
print(result) ```

I'm obtaining an empty result with your suggestion, do you know what might be wrong? Thank you

Comment: 1. You cannot use the `position()` function unless you choose the alternative approach mentioned in my answer. I am using the `xsl:number` instruction to number each row sequentially, regardless of whether it was generated by an (empty) `UpdateStep` or by a `Warning`.  2. I have tested my answer using your input and the result is what I posted. I am afraid I have no clue what the problem could be at your end. ---  P.S. Please do not post code in comments.